# Cannot insert a video into HTML page

Tags: html, video

I want to insert a video into my HTML page with the `video` tag. Here is my markdown (I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application, and symbol `~` means project root):

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="~/show.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Cannot load the video.
</video>
```

But it just shows white space with video controls. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

And the slider in the video controls does not move (i.e. the video is not playing), although the "pause" icon is shown, which should mean: the video is playing.

## What I have tried

1. Adding `src` attribute to `video` tag.
2. Opening the menu in the right of video controls panel and clicking "Download". It downloaded my video. When I played it with Windows Media Player, it showed exactly what I have recorded.
3. Removing `type` attribute from `source` tag.
4. Removing `source` tag (and leaving only `src` attribute in `video` tag).
5. Moving the slider in video controls panel. Still white space.
6. Setting `controls="controls"` in `video` tag.
7. Surfing the Internet (including Stack Overflow).
8. Now I asked my own question.

Comment: Which browser were you using?

Comment: Using Chrome browser

Comment: if you try and access the video directly, is it found? and can it play in the browser (WMP supports codecs that Chrome doesn't). Do you get any error in the developer tools | network tab of the browser?

Comment: @SNBS Use [MediaInfo (online)](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) to check if your video file contains valid A/V formats for compatible with Chrome... The sound works so the audio codec is fine, but what codec is the video picture? Check and tell us or else just provide a testable file.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal yes, I can access the video directly. I played it in browser (in an online video editor) successfully. No errors/warnings in developer tools. I tried MediaInfo. My video codec is MPEG4, which is supported by Chrome ([looked up](https://www.google.ru/search?q=chrome+supported+codecs) in the Internet).

Comment: do you have somewhere we can see the problem in action?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal the problem doesn't "act". Even the slider in video controls panel doesn't move — just a picture. I have provided that picture in question body. When I try insert a video into [a page created with an online HTML editor](https://replit.com/@SNoteBookSystem/Video#index.html), it works.

Comment: if you publish the page somewhere we can see it, then can maybe help debug.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I have published the page on Replit (follow the link in my previous comment), but it works there. I will also try to publish my whole ASP.NET MVC project (where it doesn't work).

Comment: @SNBS **(1)** Your picture shows us a not working 24 second video but your link has an working 8 minute video.  Are you testing the right file in ASP.net? **(2)** You need to show us **the actual page running** live (or in action) in a web page (not inside some online editor). If you don't have online space for uploading test pages then try [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/) and choose their **free** account/signup option. Upload your HTML and MP4 there and give us the direct link to the html file...